# Matching Dates and Moving the rows to correspond with correct dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Column A has dates over a given 10 year period (often a single date appears more than once).  Column B has each date only once and Columns C-G have values corresponding to each date in Column B.

I want to create a macro or formula to identify each date in Column A and align it with the corresponding date in Column B as well as the corresponding values in Columns C-G.

```
Column A                    Column B                  Column C
1/1/1999                    1/1/1999                    0.45
1/1/1999                    1/2/1999                    0.54
1/1/1999                    1/3/1999                    0.23
1/2/1999
1/2/1999
1/3/1999
```

Comment: By align what do you mean? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Sure, I mean copy the values in column b-g corresponding a certain date in the same row as that same date in column A next to every time the corresponding date appears in the column A.  That way the column A and column B dates will be the same with the correct values of columns C-G corresponding to that date.

Comment: I’m still not sure I understand the question.  It might help if you showed what you want the result to look like.

Comment: If the dates on Column B are sorted you could filter the dates on Column A and then delete the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want to do, I suggest that you do it in a different worksheet. 
Copy or link the column headings from Row 1 and the dates from Column A from Sheet1 to Sheet2. 
Then, on Sheet2, set cell B2 to `=A2` and set cell C2 to `=VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet1!B$2:G$10, 2, FALSE)` (replacing `10` with the last row that has a date) and drag/fill to the right and down.